# Regex to extract specific numbers in a String

Tags: c#, regex

```
string temp = "12345&refere?X=Assess9677125?Folder_id=35478";
```

I need to extract the number 12345 alone and I don't need the numbers 9677125 and 35478.

What regex can I use?

Comment: Is the number you need always at the beginning and ends with a `&`?

Comment: What is the pattern of your string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number you want is always at the beginning of the string and terminated by an ampersand (`&`) you don't need a regex at all. Just split the string on the ampersand and get the first element of the resulting array:

```
String temp = "12345&refere?X=Assess9677125?Folder_id=35478";
var splitArray = String.Split('&', temp);
var number = splitArray[0]; // returns 12345
```

Alternatively, you can get the index of the ampersand and `substring` up to that point:

```
String temp = "12345&refere?X=Assess9677125?Folder_id=35478";
var ampersandIndex = temp.IndexOf("&");
var number = temp.SubString(0, ampersandIndex); // returns 12345
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the regex for extracting 5 digit number in the beginning of the string:

```
^(\d{5})&
```

If length is arbitrary:

```
^(\d+)&
```

If termination pattern is not always `&`:

```
^(\d+)[^\d]
```

Based on the `Sayse`'s  comment you can simply rewrite as:

```
^(\d+)
```

and in case of the termination is some number(for instance `999`) then:

```
^(\d+)999
```

Comment: Why does the termination matter? All you need is to match anything thats a digit at the start of the string.

Comment: @Sayse, yes I have made a stupid thing, but it will be helpful if termination is also digit or some number.

Comment: @Sayse, see edits. The case may be all digits in the start of the string till digit 8. If the termination is `&` then of course it is nonsense and we can use just `(\d+)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex if you only want to extract the first number:

```
string temp = "12345&refere?X=Assess9677125?Folder_id=35478";

int first = Int32.Parse(String.Join("", temp.TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c))));

Console.WriteLine(first);  // 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you haven given us this is fairly simple:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<number>\d+)&");
var match = regex.Match("12345&refere?X=Assess9677125?Folder_id=35478");
if (match.Success)
{
    var number = int.Parse(match.Groups["number"].Value);
}
```

**Edit:** Of course you can replace the argument of `new Regex` with any of the combinations Giorgi has given.